# How do I open a bootstrap popover from a controller

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

I am stuck on where to start here. I want to open popovers from the angular controller when something happens.

For example, let's say the user has selected 30 checkboxes, I want to open a popover with two buttons that allow the user to "Action all Items" or "Cancel" and also have a textarea where the user can put in a comment.

Currently, I am calling external javascript function from controller. The issue here is that the popover is defined outside of the current $scope.

Like I said, I am stuck on where to start. Any help is appreciated.

Current angular code:

```
$scope.showActionCommentPopover = function () {
    var elementId = "#CommentPopoverAnchor";
    var popoverTitle = "Action Comment";
    var popoverContent = "Enter comment: <br/><textarea cols='50' rows='10' id='processComment' ng-model='actionComment'></textarea>";
    var width = "600px";
    var placement = "right";

    ShowPopover(elementId, popoverTitle, popoverContent, width, placement);
};
```

External js function:

```
function ShowPopover(elementId, popoverTitle, popoverContent, width, placement) {
    $(elementId).popover({
        placement: placement,
        title: popoverTitle + '<a class="close" data-toggle="popover" onClick="$(\'' + elementId + '\').popover(\'destroy\');">×</a>',
        content: popoverContent,
        html: true
    });
    $(elementId).popover('show');
    $(".popover").css("width", width);
    $(elementId).popover('show');
}
```